# how can we get two element per iteration in jstl in for each

Tags: jstl

I want to get two- two element per iteration in jstl. Is it posible that i do so.
Here is my code. dataListTweets is my list which i have set in previous page. i want to iterate two two element per iteration from List.

```
<table cellpadding="2"  style="margin-left: 82px;margin-top: 11px;">
            <c:forEach items="${dataListTweets}" var="Tweets">
            <tr>
                <td width="119">${Tweets}</td>
                <td width ="168">${Tweets}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:remove var="dataListDetails" scope="request"/>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specif a `step` value in the `forEach` to iterate every two items of the collections.
Then use `varStatus` to get the index of the loop to define which tweet to display.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach  step="2" items="${dataListTweets}" varStatus="vs">
        <tr>
            <td width="119">${dataListTweets[vs.index]}</td>
            <td width="168">${dataListTweets[vs.index+1]}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```